# Occasionally on start up my raspberry pi will not connect to the internet

Tags: raspbian, ssh, wireless

My setup.
Headless RPI
[With a wireless adapter.](http://thepihut.com/products/usb-wifi-adapter-for-the-raspberry-pi)

[I followed there setup on this page.](http://blog.thepihut.com/how-to-setup-wifi-on-the-raspberry-pi-raspbian/) But I have cut out the important info for you below.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove

We’ll want to take a backup of the WIFI configuration file before we start to make changes.

sudo cp /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.bak

Next up we can edit the file with the “nano” editor.

sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

We want the file to look like the screenshot below. You’ll need to swap “YOUR_SSID” and “YOUR_PASSWORD” for your WIFI name and password. Once done, save and close the nano editor
```

[image]

I filled it out and it worked. Although the problem is half the time I turn it on, it has not connected to the internet and so I cannot then connect to it with ssh.

So i have to connect into it log in then reboot to fix the problem.

I've brand new with my toy and so do not know how I should go about debugging it.

**Question: What am I doing wrong / How can I help to debug the problem.**

(I'm brand new on rpi.se.com so I do not yet have rep here to upvote and such. Thanks)

Comment: how is your adapter connected? does it drop the connection to the router or only the internet? maybe you have better luck using a powered usb hub

Comment: Yes well, I do have a powered USB hub. Although I seem to get a better strength of scan when I use one of the two inbuilt hubs for the WIFI adapter. I believe it drops all connection when I log in I sometimes get a error with the WPA_GUI that it is missing the wpa_supplicant or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be doing anything wrong.  Perhaps you just have a poor wireless system.

To debug have a look at dmesg (from a command prompt type dmesg).  It normally show some wireless dongle diagnostics.

The output of iwconfig may be of interest.

The exact dongle type (ID) as reported by lsusb may be of interest.